# Difference between "en-GB" and "en-Us" cultures names

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

When I write this code date set to something like that "12/12/2018 20:08" and it's ok

```
{
     var newCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
     var date = (value as DateTime?)?.ToString(newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern+" HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

but when i change culture name to "en-Us" the result is "12.12.2018 20:08" (not right format as i know) -returning date format of ShortDatePattern is not right

I test it on another desktop, and there it works right with 2 of them.
May be there is some kind of dependence on desktop settings?
Why date formats are various?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In US the 12 and 12 are the other way around.

Comment: I seem to remember some weird circumstance where the system would perform case sensitive comparisons rather than case insensitive ones when looking up cultures. Does anything change if you specify `en-US` instead of `en-Us`? You've also said that something is "not right" but not told us what you were expecting.

Comment: 1. culture names are case sensitive - so `"en-Us"` should be `"en-US"`. 2. Day and month are reversed between these two cultures - GB it's `dd/mm/yyyy` and US is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: i expected "12/12/2018" as on another desktop

Comment: Yes, desktop settings matter.  Use Control Panel > Language > Change date, time and number formats.  And talk to somebody about it, this was surely changed to fix some kind of problem for another program.

Comment: the problem is not right separator

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are probably thinking https://stackoverflow.com/q/53285491/11683

Comment: @ВиталийСемененя See the [Control Panel Overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2#control-panel-overrides) section.

Comment: GSerg thank you so much!!! I should set useUserOverride to false!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new CultureInfo("en-GB")` calls the ctor with `useUserOverride` set to true. This means that if you server environment has a match for the specified culture with custom settings those will be used instead of the default once. So to fix your issue `CultureInfo("en-GB", false);` or [`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) (for a cached version)

> The GetCultureInfo method retrieves a cached, read-only CultureInfo
>   object. It offers better performance than a corresponding call to the
>   CultureInfo.CultureInfo(String) constructor.
>
> If name is the name of the current culture, the returned CultureInfo
>   object **does not reflect any user overrides**. This makes the method
>   suitable for server applications or tools that do not have a real user
>   account on the system and that need to load multiple cultures
>   efficiently.